# 通報が役に立ったかどうかかはどうやって決定される？

Tags: サポート

通報を行った際に、それが役に立ったかどうかはどうやって判定されるのでしょう？

例えば、スパム通報は、おそらく自動的に動作しているような気がしていて、役に立ったかどうかの判定はシステムが行っているのではないか、と思っています。

逆に、「モデーレーターによる対応が必要です」通報は、モデーレーター以外が役に立ったかどうかを判断するのはおかしいと考えられます。

通報の種類はたくさんありますが、それぞれがどのようにして役に立った・立たなかったかは判定されますか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「モデレーターによる対応が必要です」通報には自動処理がないので、「役に立つ」「却下」はモデレーターのうちの誰かが決定します。

その他の通報には自動処理も存在しますが、それを待たずにモデレーターが返答をすることもあります。また一部の通報については[「disputed」](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95275/what-is-a-disputed-flag)という自動処理でしか発生しない返答もあります。

Comment: FWIW: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141292/what-is-the-difference-between-disputed-and-declined-flags

Comment: そして、 aged away っていうのもあるみたいですね。